# Dropdown inside Kendo Grid React Js Wrapper component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-react-ui

While creating inline editable Kendo Grid using React Js Wrapper component, came to know that you they do not have template supported yet. 
They declared the same in their website :

*Templates are only supported in the form of "strings". Templates in the form of React components are not supported.*

Is there way to do this 
along with Kendo React Wrapper Grid Component? Below is my code snippet:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';
import kendo from '@progress/kendo-ui';
import { Grid, GridColumn } from '@progress/kendo-grid-react-wrapper';
import { DropDownList } from '@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns';
import {  GridCell } from '@progress/kendo-react-grid';


class DropDownCell extends GridCell {
    handleChange(e) {
        this.props.onChange({
            dataItem: this.props.dataItem,
            field: this.props.field,
            syntheticEvent: e.syntheticEvent,
            value: e.target.value
        });
    }
    render() {
        const value = this.props.dataItem[this.props.field];

        if (!this.props.dataItem.inEdit) {
            return (
                <td> {
                    (value === null) ? '' : this.props.dataItem[this.props.field].toString()}
                </td>
            );
        }

        return (
            <td>
                <DropDownList
                    style={{ width: "100px" }}
                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                    value={value}
                    data={[
                        { text: 'yes', value: true },
                        { text: 'no', value: false },
                        { text: '(empty)', value: null }
                    ]}
                    valueField="value"
                    textField="text"
                />
            </td>
        );
    }
}

class AppComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.onDataBound = function(){
            $(".toolbar").html(
                `<tr>
                    <td>
                </tr>`
            );       
         }

        this.state = {
            products :[
                { ProductID: 1,ProductName: "Chai",SupplierID: 1,CategoryID: 1,QuantityPerUnit: "10 boxes x 20 bags",UnitPrice: 18.0000,UnitsInStock: 39,UnitsOnOrder: 0,ReorderLevel: 10,Discontinued: false,Category: { CategoryID: 1,CategoryName: "Beverages",Description: "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales"}},
                { ProductID: 2,ProductName: "Chang",SupplierID: 1,CategoryID: 1,QuantityPerUnit: "24 - 12 oz bottles",UnitPrice: 19.0000,UnitsInStock: 17,UnitsOnOrder: 40,ReorderLevel: 25,Discontinued: false,Category: {CategoryID: 1,CategoryName: "Beverages",Description: "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales"}},
                {ProductID: 3,ProductName: "Aniseed Syrup",SupplierID: 1,CategoryID: 2,QuantityPerUnit: "12 - 550 ml bottles",UnitPrice: 10.0000,UnitsInStock: 13,UnitsOnOrder: 35,ReorderLevel: 25,Discontinued: false,Category: {CategoryID: 2,CategoryName: "Condiments",Description: "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"}},
                {ProductID: 4,ProductName: "Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning",SupplierID: 2,CategoryID: 2,QuantityPerUnit: "48 - 6 oz jars",UnitPrice: 22.0000,UnitsInStock: 53,UnitsOnOrder: 0,ReorderLevel: 0,Discontinued: false,Category: {CategoryID: 2,CategoryName: "Condiments",Description: "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads,  seasonings"}},
                {ProductID: 5,ProductName: "Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix",SupplierID: 2,CategoryID: 2,QuantityPerUnit: "36 boxes",UnitPrice: 21.3500,UnitsInStock: 0,UnitsOnOrder: 0,ReorderLevel: 0,Discontinued: true,Category: {CategoryID: 2,CategoryName: "Condiments",Description: "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"}},
                {ProductID: 6,ProductName: "Grandma's Boysenberry Spread",SupplierID: 3,CategoryID: 2,QuantityPerUnit: "12 - 8 oz jars",UnitPrice: 25.0000,UnitsInStock: 120,UnitsOnOrder: 0,ReorderLevel: 25,Discontinued: false,Category: {CategoryID: 2,CategoryName: "Condiments",Description: "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, seasonings"}},
                {ProductID: 7,ProductName: "Uncle Bob's Organic Dried Pears",SupplierID: 3,CategoryID: 7,QuantityPerUnit: "12 - 1 lb pkgs.",UnitPrice: 30.0000,UnitsInStock: 15,UnitsOnOrder: 0,ReorderLevel: 10,Discontinued: false,Category: {CategoryID: 7,CategoryName: "Produce",Description: "Dried fruit and bean curd"}},
                {ProductID: 8,ProductName: "Northwoods Cranberry Sauce",SupplierID: 3,CategoryID: 2,QuantityPerUnit: "12 - 12 oz jars",UnitPrice: 40.0000,UnitsInStock: 6,UnitsOnOrder: 0,ReorderLevel: 0,Discontinued: false,Category: {CategoryID: 2,CategoryName: "Condiments",Description: "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads,  seasonings"}},
                {ProductID: 9,ProductName: "Mishi Kobe Niku",SupplierID: 4,CategoryID: 6,QuantityPerUnit: "18 - 500 g pkgs.",UnitPrice: 97.0000,UnitsInStock: 29,UnitsOnOrder: 0,ReorderLevel: 0,Discontinued: true,Category: {CategoryID: 6,CategoryName: "Meat/Poultry",Description: "Prepared meats"}},
                {ProductID: 10,ProductName: "Ikura",SupplierID: 4,CategoryID: 8,QuantityPerUnit: "12 - 200 ml jars",UnitPrice: 31.0000,UnitsInStock: 31,UnitsOnOrder: 0,ReorderLevel: 0,Discontinued: false,Category: {CategoryID: 8,CategoryName: "Seafood",Description: "Seaweed and fish"}}
            ]
        };

        this.dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: this.state.products,
            pageSize: 5,
            schema:{
                model:{
                    field:{
                        ProductID: {type:"number"},
                        ProductName:{type:"string"},
                        Discontinued:{type:"boolean"}

                    }
                }
            }
        }); 
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Grid 
                dataSource={this.dataSource}
                filterable={true}
                editable={true  }
                sortable={true}
                pageable={true}
                groupable={true}
                editable={"inline"}
                dataBound={this.onDataBound}>
                <GridColumn field="Discontinued" title="Discontinued" cell={DropDownCell} />
                <GridColumn field="SupplierID" title="Supperlie Id"/>
                <GridColumn field="CategoryID" title="Category Id"/>
                <GridColumn field="QuantityPerUnit" title="Quantity Per Unit"/>
                <GridColumn command={["edit", "destroy"]} title="&nbsp;" width="200px" />
                </Grid>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AppComponent;
```

Comment: Posted the same query over telerik blog and find out the way to do it, Below link has that support ticket :https://www.telerik.com/forums/react-grid-with-dropdown-in-column#qyBJzYgwUkaYf0W2_rFPWg

Comment: Telerik provided one more example : https://next.plnkr.co/edit/z5CrVABIZYaGFoRP